# MATLAB: secure share a function

Tags: matlab, deployment, share

I have written a MATLAB standalone function `myfun.m` and I would like to share it with people who also have MATLAB. They can use the function but I don't want them to see what's inside the function.

So far I have seen 1 way to do this with `pcode`: I would create `myfun.p` using `pcode('myfun.m')` then I would share `myfun.p` with people. **Is this correct?**

The approach above seems to have 2 problems:

- when I type `help myfun`, I get `No help found for myfun.p.` although I have created a short help for the original .m (via a comment immediately following the function declaration)
- mathworks [says](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html) that the .p file contains an obscured, not encrypted, version of the original .m

**Is there another approach besides `pcode` that rectifies either or both of the issues above?**

Comment: why do you want to obfuscate the code if I may ask?

Comment: @percusse Privacy to the users actually. The content of the function reveals too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. All comments are removed when generating a `.p` file from an `.m` file including all help text. If you want to provide help text for your `.p` file, you can create a separate `.m` file with the same name as the `.p` file that contains *only* the help text. Due to the order of function resolution, the `.p` file will be evaluated when it's used programmatically, and the `.m` file will be referenced when looking for help.

   Note the ordering of `.p` and `.m` files in the following table from the Mathworks:

   > When determining the precedence of functions within the same folder, MATLAB considers the file type, in this order:
   >
   > 1. Built-in function
   > 2. MEX-function
   > 3. Simulink model files that are not loaded, with file types in this order:
   > 4. SLX file
   > 5. MDL file
   > 6. App file (.mlapp) created using MATLAB App Designer
   > 7. Program file with a .mlx extension
   > 8. P-file (that is, an encoded program file with a .p extension)
   > 9. Program file with a .m extension
2. This is true, the contents of the `.p` file are obfuscated but it is not trivial for a user to reverse engineer the contents of the file so it's likely not worth their effort to do so. You can find several utilities that claim to produce `.m` files from `.p` files, but those `.m` files are likely not going to look anything like the original source.

   If you're really concerned about the security of your algorithms, you could always write the sensitive parts within a compiled mex file.

Comment: Thank you for your guide in 1. and reassurance in 2. The content of the function is sensitive but not critically so. I'm content now with `pcode`.